# Twitter @anywhere using chrome Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, twitter, twitter-anywhere

im trying to iplement twitter @anywhere ,
to detect current twitter user info ,

```
twttr.anywhere(function(T){
    if (T.isConnected()) {
         currentUser = T.currentUser;
         screenName = currentUser.data('screen_name');
         alert(screenName);
         return true;
     }
     else {
     return false;
     };
});
```

when loading page i get in console : 
"Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://api.twitter.com/xd_receiver.html from frame with URL about:blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match."

i've checked the Registered Callback URL and it's ok , 
everything should work ok ,

any idea what's wrong ?

tnx

Comment: I think you'll have to give us more context about the HTML and other JS that runs this because the problem is being caused by the context this script is run in, not the piece of script you've shown us.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time, but I'm having this problem now.

In [this blog](http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2010/04/twit-connect-with-anywhere/), Shannon Whitley said what appears to be the problem.

If you are on “www…” in your browser then try removing it (or vice-versa).